# The action 'index' could not be found for Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a controller with one action and when i try and go to the localhost:3000/controllername/action i get this error:

The action 'show' could not be found for LearnController

Here is my controller:

```
class LearnController < ApplicationController

    def more

    end
end
```

and in routes i do this:

```
resources :learn
```

I know that resources creates all the show, edit, index and all that but how do I make it so only the actions i create are created in the routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, `resources :learn` will create a bunch of routes according to the resourceful convention.

If you don't want those, don't use `resources` in your `config/routes.rb` file.  Instead, use `get`, `match`, and friends to define your routes manually.  E.g.

```
get 'learn/more'
```

Comment: thanks! and another thing is after following this tutorial for a while it keeps wanting me to use scaffolding which is really easy and quick to use but I want to know how to create an app from scratch and not have to use scaffolding to make them for me, is there any tutorial you recommend on learning this?

Comment: Two things.  First, the ROR guides are fantastic: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/.  Second, the scaffolds, in a way, are a fine tutorial.  In normal development it's perfectly fine to use a generator to get the boilerplate files setup for a new model/controller/resource.  The scaffolding just goes one small step extra and generates sample views.  I would encourage using the scaffold as a learning tool, but when you're ready, use the other generators instead.